# GCP instance installed libraries not working

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, instance

I installed some python packages in my gcp instance. python_speech_features was one of them. When I wrote pip list, it shows me that it is installed. But when I try to access it in my code, it says no module found with this name python_speech_features. I have attached screenshots of the error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkueo.png) and installed packages [packages installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP4I6.png).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't include screenshots of code, it makes it hard copy/paste and for your answer to show up in search results.

Comment: Can you show us how you installed the package (what command you used) and the command you used to list the installed packages?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate a scenario like the one you currently have; however, I was able to use the ’python_speech_features’ library with this [example](https://github.com/jameslyons/python_speech_features/blob/master/example.py) on a GCE instance without issues. This is the procedure I did:

1. [Create an GCE instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux#create_a_virtual_machine_instance) and connect it.
2. Create a virtual environment with this command: `virtualenv -p python3 env`
3. Activate the virtualenv with this command: `source env/bin/activate`
4. Install the following libraries:

   - numpy==1.18.5
   - python-speech-features==0.5
   - scipy==1.4.1
5. Download the [example file](https://github.com/jameslyons/python_speech_features/blob/master/english.wav): ‘example.wav’
6. Run the code: ‘python example.py’

I recommend trying this procedure to ensure that the library import works correctly.